# Android - how to show progress dialog while service is running?

Tags: android, service

I want to create a service, that downloads content from web and I want to show progress dialog while it is executing. I know how to use progress dialog with asynctask and volley, but here I have no idea, now can I be notified on UI thread about service ending when using service.

How can I accomplish this ?

Code is following

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

public void onClickStart(View v) {
  startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

public void onClickStop(View v) {
  stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

}


public class MyService extends Service {

  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
  }

  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
    someTask();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }

  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  void someTask() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++) {
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "i = " + i);
          try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        stopSelf();
      }
    }).start();
  }
```

Comment: For services, you should show notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create broadcast messages when you want to show or hide progress bar from your service:

```
Intent i = new Intent("yourPackage.SHOW_Progress");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

then create broadcast receiver and handle received messages:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         MainActivity mainActivity = ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).mainActivity;
         mainActivity.showProgress();
    }

}
```

and inside your mainActivity create method for show or hide progress bar

Comment: Thanks for reply! Question - argument inside Intent ("yourPackage.SHOW_Progress") is obligatorily or there can be everything inside brackets ? Can I reference special intents inside onReceive depending on argument of intent ?

Comment: Argument inside intent is the action of intent it can be everything you like but must be same as the argument you register in manifest file receiver section.**2** you can send one broadcast intent and set multiple intent extra values depending on what action you want

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are my saver!

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to communicate between a Service and an Activity.

You could send a Broadcast from the Service and process it in the Activity with a BroadcastReceiver.

Or you could as well bind the Service and send any command back when the service has finished doing its task.

Comment: though this does not SOLVE the problem, it is a concise answer which places all others in context.  UPVOTED  :)